# Header файлы и их проблема подключения

Tags: c++, header, mingw

Работаю над проектом с компилятором MinGW32, компилирую в cmd.exe и столкнулся с проблемой:
  Создал header-файл(UIClass.h) создаю его файл.cpp(mainWindow.cpp) в файл подключаю UIClass и получается это...

UIClass.h

```
#ifndef _UICLASS_H_
#define _UICLASS_H_
class UIClass {
public:
   void mainWindow();
   void message(char text[]);
};
#endif /* _UICLASS_H_ */
```

mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "UIClass.h"
#include "SaveText.h"

void UICLass::mainWindow() {
  SaveText file;  

  while(1) {
    message("ХХХ");
    break;
  }
}
```

Лог компилятора:

```
mainWindow.cpp:4:6: error: 'UICLass' has not been declared
 void UICLass::mainWindow() {
      ^
mainWindow.cpp: In function 'void mainWindow()':
mainWindow.cpp:8:60: error: 'message' was not declared in this scope
     message("ХХХ");
                                                            ^
```

Я всё пересмотрел, никаких проблем не заметил. Должно же работать, но как видите...

Почему компилятор не видит мой класс, и вообще что с ним происходит? Однажды он у меня не видел библиотеку  в итоге методом тыка он его нашёл.

Comment: Компилируете оба файла? И MainWindow, и UIClass?

Comment: У вас в .cpp файле большая L в UICLass

Comment: @Byulent а для чего компилить хедер? я всегда думал что с него просто читается код.

Comment: @SilentiumNoxe Я думал, что имеется и UIClass.cpp

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов Вы бы оформили свой комментарий как ответ.

Comment: блин, походу заработался)) реально большая 'L'. А я всё уже пересмотрел и нифига не видел, что пришлось сюда писать, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .cpp файле большая L в UICLass 
(оформил в виде ответа)